# prevent from writing to a large continuous section of virtual memory

Tags: kernel, virtual-memory

How can an operating system kernel efficiently prevent a user process from writing to a large continuous section of virtual memory?

Comment: Why would it want to do so? Processes using contiguous areas of virtual memory are *beneficial* to performance.

Comment: You'll probably need to give more background or a better explanation if you want useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

Virtual memory is provided by the [MMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit), a hardware component. Only the kernel is allowed to modify the MMU configuration. The MMU configuration determines what physical address (if any) each virtual address corresponds to, and what permissions the program has at this address (at least read or read-write, the exact capabilities depend on the hardware architecture).

The kernel can prevent a process from writing to a chunk of virtual memory by ensuring that these addresses are mapped read-only or not mapped at all.

If this is homework, it may be fishing for you to explain how the MMU on your architecture works, and in particular how to use higher-level directories (sections, L1/L2 tables, or whatever they're called on your architecture) as opposed to lower-level directories (L2/L3).

Answer (score 0):

On Unix-like systems, the mprotect system call is used to control memory protection:

Details:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_protection

Comment: Not exactly. `mprotect` allows the process to control its own memory access. The (admittedly vague) question asks how the kernel can prevent a process from doing this (specifically from getting write access).

Comment: OK , you are right , i didn’t interpret the question correctly.